# Spring 4.0 Concurrent Session Control configuration not working

Tags: java, session, spring-security, concurrency

I am trying to implement Spring concurrent session control in my project with spring security version 4.0. I have implemented custom class that extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. Below is my configuration.

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Security Configuration

So as per my understanding, I need to replace the default `NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy` in `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to `concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`. And that should to do the trick. So whenever a session is created/destroyed `HttpSessionEventPulisher` will notify to `concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` and it will add/remove that session from `SessionRegistry`. By default `maximumSessions` are set to one, so if a user will try to login more than once; `concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` will throw an error. But with the configuration below authentication strategy is not getting set to concurrent.

```
http
.sessionManagement()
.sessionAuthenticationStrategy(concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy());

@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry(){
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(){
    return new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());

}
```

I am able to set it from the subclass using

```
setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy);
```

but in this case SessionResgistry is always empty no matter how many times I login with the same user. Can somebody guide if I have understood it right how concurrent session control works in spring or if there is anything that I have missed in my configuration. Thanks for your help. appreciate it.